# kannel configuration file to send sms from localhost to moble

Tags: linux, kannel

I am new to kannel and want to send messages from my localhost machine to my mobile number, but I can't figure out how to start with the configuration file

Any help in this topic will be highly appreciated. I have tried a few configuration files but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Kannel is a server application where you can connect it to the operators SMSC in-order to send sms's. In this case, you must get a account from the operator. Otherwise you can connect a mobile / GSM modem to your localhost and access it via Kannel to send SMS.

Comment: That doesn't explain how to set up the configuration file - could you add an example of something that might work?

Comment: First of all sorry for the delay reply. you can refer this article for the basic configuration and usage : http://mobiforge.com/design-development/sending-sms-with-smpp-kannel-and-java